# Applicative Functor on Lists

Tags: haskell, applicative

I understand that following will be:

```
[(+2),(+1)]<*>[1,2,3] == [3,4,5,2,3,4]
```

I also understand that `fmap` is implemented as `map`. But how could I mentally map this computation in my head? The first time I saw this I assumed the following:

```
[(*2),(+1)]<*>[1,2,3] == [4,5,6]
```

The second time around I though about: `[[3,4,5],[2,3,4]]`. But on the other hand `<*>` returns an `f b` so I knew it wouldn't be possible. So my question is, what are the mental steps to make sense out of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`fs <*> xs` is more-or-less `[f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]`.  Monads have the Applicative instance

```
fM <*> xM = do 
  f <- fM
  x <- xM
  return (f x)
```

which corresponds to the list comprehension pretty directly.

Answer (score 8):

To remember this you might find it easier to simply imagine `<*>` to be `×` (Cartesian product):

```
[a, b, c] × [x, y, z] == [a x, a y, a z, b x, b y, ...]
```

Comment: And in fact, `(,) <$> xs <*> ys` produces a representation of `xs × ys`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  Does an applicative always *have* to be the cartesian product?   Or is the strategy really a matter of choice.  For instance could a "zip" of two lists also be valid? ie:

> [F1,F2,F3] <*> [a,b,c] == [F1 a, F2 b, F3 c]

Comment: It could. This is implemented in Control.Applicative.ZipList.